# cfx run is not working

Tags: sdk, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I downloaded the sdk tool and i installed the python 2.7.8 also. While activating the sdk tool its working fine. Even while i am running cfx int command it is creating all required directory inside the folder in which i run.
But while running cfx run command it is showing error:

**I can't find the application binary in any of its default locations
on your system. Please specify one using the -b/--binary option.**
[image: cfx run error example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell cfx where to find Firefox, eg

`cfx -b c:\path\to\firefox.exe run`